# Поместить код в модуль

Tags: jquery, javascript

помогите пожалуйста поместить код в модуль

на [страничке](http://jsfiddle.net/sTG7M/) я через скрипт добавил некоторый функционал кнопкам. хотелось бы изолировать код, отвечающий за функционал(my observer begin) в модуль. пример кода модуля в моём примере тоже есть(my module begin)

Comment: Что все это значит? )))

Comment: вам jQuery на что дана ? думаете чтобы усложнить код до нечитаемости ?

Comment: @eicto, он еще про jquery не слышал, а вы - упреки! ))))

Comment: @Deus у него в fiddle jQuery подключено и используется.

Comment: следуя вашей логике ассемблер давно устарел и от него пора уже отказаться.
ребят, есть задача. я её сформулировал, если сказать нечего, лучше промолчать

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin да непонятно чего вы хотите, выглядит ваш код ужасно, мне даже непонятно что именно он делает и зачем. [(вы не сформулировали задачу, в js нет понятия модуль, и он точно не имеет отношения к тому объекту, созданному в замыкании непонятно зачем именно таким образом, который показан в конце)](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#volume) (и причем тут ассемблер ?) Следуя моей логике - на javascript не надо писать как на ассемблере.

Comment: как это в js нет понятия модуль?
http://www.libraries.com.ua/?p=5352&page=72
модуль этот популярный шаблон проектирования, который используется в 90% любых js-проектов. вы в курсе темы вообще?

а задачу я сформулировал как раз ясно и лаконично))) "добавил функционал кнопками. необходимо поместить его в модуль".

если вам "не очень понятно что делает код", то я тоже поясню. это небольшой учебный пример шаблона проектированя observer, на котором кстати основана событийная модель(.on) вашего любимого jquery.
как понимаете, учебный пример вполне может быть не слишком полезным практически

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin вы неумный человек. Мне понятен шаблон модуль  и его здесь нет(если некто Стоян Стефанов пользуется собственной терминологией, то надо изначально на него ссылаться, хотя я вот почитал, он видимо пытается java из js сделать - дурацкая затея). А шаблон observer уже реализован в jQuery, поэтому я вас и спрашиваю, зачем вы его переизобретаете.

Comment: ваша манера общения выдаёт вас с головой))) удачи в жизни)))